# Logstash does not insert into elasticsearch (from file piped into stdin)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to insert the [NYC taxi data](http://www.andresmh.com/nyctaxitrips/) into elasticsearch via Logstash.
with the command `bin/logstash -f myconf.conf < /trip_data1.csv`

But I get...

`Logstash startup completed
Logstash shutdown completed`

Where apparently nothing happened. No index has been created/modified in Elasticsearch either.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is my conf file:

```
input {
  stdin{}
}

filter {
csv {
    columns => ["medallion","hack_license","vendor_id","rate_code","store_and_fwd_flag","pickup_datetime","dropoff_datetime","passenger_count","trip_time_in_secs","trip_distance","pickup_longitude","pickup_latitude","dropoff_longitude","dropoff_latitude"]
    separator => ","
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "samples1"
    document_type => "sample"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try with --debug ?

Comment: I tried the exact same config as you have above and it went perfectly well and I can see data in my ES. So either your config or data file is not named properly or your ES doesn't have the default configuration (port and cluster_name). Can you double check?

Comment: It turns out one index (inside the Logstash node) was corrupted. I didn't know how to fix a Logstash index so I just uninstalled Logstash and deleted all its data and reinstalled it.

Comment: Ok, good you figured out.

Comment: Another case may be in sincedb seek position.